# Android drawable resources strange behaviour

Tags: android, xml, image, resources

I have 26 weather icons in a folder and all load and display. When I added two more those two don't show up for some reason. The app loads fine and there are no errors, but there is an empty space where the Icon image should have loaded.

I have a similar problem with the background image of the app. At first it would stretch in landscape mode (it's a portrait image), so I created a centered_bg.xml file which contains a bitmap element and src of the image and gravity:center. In Android studio the preview shows the correct behaviour, the image is centered in both portrait and landscape, but when I run the app on my Note 3 device the background image does not display.

centered_bg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/london"
    android:gravity="center"></bitmap>
```

layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/centered_bg">
...
```

I also had an OutOfMemory error when I tried to load the high res image (it's only 700kb) but adding `android:largeHeap="true"` to the manifest fixed this. The image loads when linked directly in the layout file but when it is in centered_bg.xml it doesn't show.

How can I get these images to load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The background image placed in the drawable folder was 72dpi. Android assumes it is 160dpi and scales up the image from 1920x1080 to something greater than the max dimensions OpenGL can handle, and then the image fails to load.

OpenGL has a max dimension limit of 4096x4096.

The solution was to put the image in a folder called `drawable-nodpi` or otherwise make it smaller. I rescaled the image in Photoshop to 1280px on the higher dimension at 160dpi and the image loaded fine.